# Internet explorer not detecting the plugin

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, firebreath

I have created a npapi plugin using firebreath. The plugin is detected by all browsers except Internet Explorer 10. It is not displayed in the manage addons list where plugins and extensions are displayed. I tried on both windows 7 32 bit as well as 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX Controls such as FireBreath plugins do not show up on the addons list until after they are loaded.  Try loading it using an object tag, such as with the auto-generated FBControl.htm file

Comment: It is neither showing up nor working. As if the plugin is not installed

Comment: alright it got displayed in IE and plugin was loaded, but it is not invoked for the registered mime-type.

Comment: well, which mimetype is it?

Comment: application/zip and others

Comment: It is likely, then, that the mimetype you're trying to co-opt is not one that the browser is willing to give you.  Try something like application/x-foobarbazthingy and see if that works.

Comment: I tried but it is still not working. Is there any way to find out any error if there could be, control is not being transferred to plugin

Comment: Tools such as Process Monitor can help you see what is going on, but sounds like it's either not registered or not registered correctly.  Are you using 64 bit IE w/ a 32 bit plugin? That would do it.

Comment: I tried on both 64 bit as well as 32 bit IExplorer, but didn't work. I don't wish to create a BHO now.

Comment: I have never tried it with as many mimetypes as you seem to have; I'd simplify things and try it out.  Try FBTestPlugin, see if that works, try to figure out what is different.  Not sure what to tell you